# How does xUnit runner handle static methods w/static class constructor?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, xunit.net, xunit

If I have a class with static Facts (test methods) and the class has a static constructor, is the constructor called for each Fact or only once for all Facts in a class?  I guess it depends on how the runner loads/unloads test classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of experience, I know that it is only called once for the class. It is the same if you use a static class (i.e. settings class) in your non-static tests (facts). The static object constructor is only called once for the whole test class.

Comment: thanks!  while we're on the topic, any idea of what happens with non-static methods/constructors?  Is the class instantiated once and then each method is called or are there separate instantiations per method?

Comment: The class in which the tests reside is constructor then destructed once for each test. So if there are 10 facts in a class, it will be instantiated 10 times then destructed 10 times. Any non-static object will be recreated. Any static object will be re-used.

Answer (score 0):

If anything (eg. Facts) use static method or class first time that static constructor is **called ones**. If there are no references to the static class the static constructor **is not called** at all. If you are considering to run code before and after the tests (setup/dispose) **ONES** I recommend to use Fixtures (see https://xunit.net/docs/shared-context).